# How can there be a change in the Gibbs free energy?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy

Changes in the Gibbs free energy, defined as G = H-TS, where H is the enthalpy, T is the temperature and S is the entropy, gives us the change in the free energy (or availability) of a substance during an isobaric and isothermal process. For example, if we have a chemical reaction which starts and ends at thermal equilibrium with the surroundings (usually the air in the laboratory), then the Gibbs free energy can be used to find this change in the availability. But isn't the natural variables for G just the pressure and temperature (i.e. the Gibbs energy is a function of pressure and temperature, G=G(T,p))? So if the process starts and ends at the same temperature and pressure, then how can there possibly be a change in the Gibbs free energy?

Comment: For a mixture, G is a function not only of T and P, but also the proportions of the various species in the mixture.

Answer (score 3):

Isnt it true that if  $p,T$ are held fixed then
$$
dG= \mu_1 dn_1 +\mu_2 dn_2+\ldots?
$$
Here the $\mu_i$ are the chemical potentials and $n_i$ the numbers of material of species $i$.  In *chemical process*  the $n_i$ change and the equilibrium $dG=0$ is given by a set of relations between the $\mu_i$ that are determined by  conservation relations, such as
$$
dn_{H_20}+ dn_{H^+}+ dn_{OH^-}=0
$$
among the $n_i$.

Comment: I haven't got to chemical thermodynamics yet, but your answer seems convincing. In my book, there is a chapter on thermodynamic potentials, the Gibbs free energy being one of them, and here they only said that the Gibbs energy is a function of temperature and pressure, causing my confusion.

Comment: Quite a reasonable confusion then!

Answer (score 0):

> But isn't the natural variables for G just the pressure and
> temperature (i.e. the Gibbs energy is a function of pressure and
> temperature, $G=G(T,p)$?

Not sure what makes you think that.

In a 'spontaneous' chemical reaction:

$$\Delta G = \Delta H-T\Delta S\tag{1}$$

for a reaction starting and ending at the same $T$.

In $(1)$:

1. $\Delta H$ is the summed change of all the bond enthalpies, moving from state $1$ to  state $2$.
2. $\Delta S$ is related to the probability of state $1$ to state $2$ and the difference in entropy they represent.

Where $\Delta G <0$ we say the reaction is 'spontaneous' (a misleading term, I feel)

When equilibrium has been achieved, then $\mathrm{d}G =0$.

Comment: Yes, but if you have a closed system (i.e. no transfer of matter between the system and the surroundings), then the Gibbs free energy will only be a function of temperature and pressure (in general, it's a function of pressure, temperature and the number of particles, which is proven by showing that an infinitesimal change in the Gibbs energy is a linear combination of the infinitesimal changes in p, T and N), meaning the change in the Gibbs energy is 0 for a isobaric and isothermal process.

Comment: @FelisSuper Typically, in chemical reactions (I'm a chemist) there's no matter transfer, yet $\Delta G$ is calculated as I showed. Ref.:  https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Supplemental_Modules_(Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry)/Thermodynamics/Energies_and_Potentials/Free_Energy/Gibbs_(Free)_Energy

Comment: @FelisSuper Exothermic reactions will of course lose heat to the environment (e.g. a typical fuel combustion reaction)

Comment: I know that, but it is your definition of the Gibbs free energy, as dG=dH-TdS, that made it confusing for me. For if you plug in dH=d(U+pV)=dU+pdV (using the definition H=U+pV, and assuming the pressure is constant, as in a isobaric process), and using dU=TdS-pdV (the fundamental thermodynamic relation), then you just get dG=0 (i.e. no change in the Gibbs free energy). But it seems like mike stone is offering the solution by noting that the relation dU=TdS-pdV only holds if the number of moles of the various kinds of molecules stay the same.